# UWP Pivot control adaptive layout error when targeting 1803 (spring creators update)

Tags: uwp, pivot

My UWP app targets Windows 10 Version 1803 SDK 17134 (min version is Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, SDK 16299).
I have a simple user control that displays a Pivot control with 4 PivotItems. One of those PivotItems contains another Pivot. Problem occurs when the PivotItem right of the one containing the nested Pivot control is selected and window width is somewhere near or above 3200 pixels. At this size the Pivot control will display contents of the selected PivotItem and additionally the content of the nested PivotItem.

[image: correct display at 3074 pixels width]

[image: incorrect display at 3216 pixels]

This behavior can be reproduced by creating an empty UWP app with above mentioned min and target versions and by pasting the following code into MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="App1.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:App1"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Header="TextBox1 PivotItem 1" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox2 PivotItem 1" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox3 PivotItem 1" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox4 PivotItem 1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 3">
            <Pivot>
                <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 3.1">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox1 PivotItem 3.1" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox2 PivotItem 3.1" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox3 PivotItem 3.1" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox4 PivotItem 3.1" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 3.2">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox1 PivotItem 3.2" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox2 PivotItem 3.2" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox3 PivotItem 3.2" />
                        <TextBox Header="TextBox4 PivotItem 3.2" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 3">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Header="TextBox1 PivotItem 3" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox2 PivotItem 3" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox3 PivotItem 3" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox4 PivotItem 3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 4">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Header="TextBox1 PivotItem 4" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox2 PivotItem 4" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox3 PivotItem 4" />
                <TextBox Header="TextBox4 PivotItem 4" />
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This seems to be a error related to spring creators update as the error vanishes upon using Fall Creators Update as min and target version.
Has anyone experienced the same issue and has some advice on how to get around this problem without changing the page's layout?

Comment: The [template online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299143.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says it's from 1511. Maybe try copy and paste that as a custom style and see if the proper behavior returns?

Comment: By testing on my local PC which resolution is `1920*1080` I cannot reproduce your issue. So could you please tell what 's your device and detail resolution? Did you have a device with lower resolution for testing?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT: as mentioned in the question this problem occurs around 3200 pixels screen width. Our test scenario is a 27" UHD monitor with 3840x2160 pixels resolution. Our software follows the Microsoft guidelines for adaptivity and needs to run properly on screens from 5" to at least 55" at UHD resolution. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @SeanO'Neil: that might do the trick as setting the target version to Fall Creators Update solves the problem too. But before applying a workaround to a possible bug in UWP introduced in the current SDK I would like to know if the bug will be fixed in an upcomig release. ;-) Nevertheless, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @SBeltz We've tested on a 3840x2160 27" HP z27s UHD monitor and we cannot reproduce this issue. Do you have any other device which can reproduce this issue? We might need more info to know the specific reason.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT, thanks for reaching out! My device is a 27" DELL P2715Q at 3840x2160 pixels resolution, text scaling is set to 150%. You can find a very simple repro here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlX_rLCnGmDggr1jyPAl2QI0vx-kPg

Comment: Unfortunately, with the same configuration we still cannot reproduce your issue. It may be the device special issue, but we don't have the same device as you. So   I suggest that you might need to open a support ticket about this. Please contact our paid phone support at MS Support. You will get 1:1 support on that. Please kindly note that your support ticket will be free if it is Microsoft's issue.